# Spring Security and OIDC IllegalArgumentException: Missing attribute when attribute is in id token

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to configure a Spring Security (5.4.5) OIDC authentication with Azure AD
I would like to use **preferred_username** as user name attribute
I set **profile** and **openid** as scope

Currently it fails with following:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing attribute
> 'preferred_username' in attributes    at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User.(DefaultOAuth2User.java:72)
> at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.DefaultOAuth2UserService.loadUser(DefaultOAuth2UserService.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService.loadUser(OidcUserService.java:109)

while preferred_username is in id token attributes. Debugging the code it fails because preferred_username is not in attributes returned by userInfo endpoints, but this failure seems wrong to me. If i manage to pass DefaultOAuth2User instantiation (by giving an attribute among userInfo), I see later in the code the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser` returned by `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserService` is looking at both id tokens and userInfo attributes, so prefered_username would have succeed there.

It seems like a spring security bug to me am I right or wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking more deeply in the code it definitely looks like a bug so I raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9722